# Potentials between endolymph/cytoplasm and endolymph/perilymph

Tags: hearing, membrane

I am studying for an exam and there is something I can't seem to understand. My textbook says that the endolymph contains 150mM potassium, 2mM Na+ and 130mM Cl-. The perilymph contains 5mM potassium, 140mM Na+ and 110mM Cl-. "Thus" the electric potential between perilymph and endolymph is +80mV (endolymph being positive).

I can see that there are **chemical** gradients but why is the endolymph so much more positively charged than the perilymph?

- I've already asked this question before and it was closed as a "homework question", which I would need to give suggestions on myself. 
  However, I seriously don't know what to suggest because I do not have the faintest idea how the endolymph can be +80mV as compared to perilymph, although the listed ions suggest that the surplus of positive charges is higher in the perilymph. I would love to make suggestions but I honestly don't have a clue.

Thank you in advance!